# How to obtain service credentials for a service instance created on IBM Bluemix without binding the instance to an application on Bluemix?

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, cleardb

I have created a ClearDB MySQL instance on IBM Bluemix. Can I see the credentials (hostname, username, password etc) without binding the instance to an application running on Bluemix ?

Thank you, Sandhya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if the service provider implemented the Service Keys feature. If they have, you can generate new credentials by clicking on "Service Credentials" on the service dashboard page.

The ClearDB currently requires you to bind it to a Cloud Foundry application for service credentials.